# Why can I pass an F# function to a System.Func parameter only in a member method?

Tags: function, f#

This works:

```
type MyType () =
    static member MyFn (fn : Func<bool>) = fn.Invoke ()

MyType.MyFn (fun _ -> false)
```

This does not (error FS0002):

```
let myFn (fn : Func<bool>) = fn.Invoke ()

myFn (fun _ -> false)
```

Neither does this (error FS0002):

```
type MyDU = Fn of Func<bool>

Fn (fun _ -> false)
```

What is the reason for this rather annoying inconsistency?

Comment: Interestingly, if you bind the function to a value (`let a = fun _ -> false`) and *then* call `MyType.MyFn a`, it doesn't work. You get this error instead: "FS0001: This expression was expected to have type `Func<bool>` but here has type `'a -> bool`".

Comment: This question was closed, but I don't think it covers exactly the same ground as the proposed duplicate (specifically regarding the intent to limit this behavior to methods), so I've reopened it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This behavior is covered by section 8.13.7 (Type-directed Conversions at Member Invocations) of the [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf), where it states:

> Note: These type-directed conversions are primarily for
>   interoperability with existing member-based .NET libraries and do not
>   apply at invocations of functions defined in modules or bound locally
>   in expressions.